# ОШИБКА: для типа данных text не определён класс операторов по умолчанию для метода доступа "gin"

Tags: postgresql

Когда пытаюсь создать индекс в postgreSQl, в pgMyAdmin.

Ошибка SQL:

ОШИБКА:  для типа данных text не определён класс операторов по умолчанию для метода доступа "gin"
HINT:  Вы должны указать класс операторов для индекса или определить класс операторов по умолчанию для этого типа данных.
В операторе:
CREATE INDEX "seacrh_text" ON "public"."directories" USING GIN ("data")

Comment: А с каких это пор php*my*admin научился pg? И что именно вы хотите сделать с текстом? Как вы себе представляете gin индекс по тексту?

Comment: Я тут спрашивал, не отвечают. 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729068/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-postgresql

Comment: А как мне выполнить полнотекстовый поиск по столбцу с текстом?

Comment: Я так понял, что чтобы создать индекс, поле должно иметь тип tsvector, а не text.
Получается я должен вручную создавать еще один столбец, и при каждом обновлении поля text затем и обновлять поле tsvector?

Comment: В интернете во всех примерах этот код работает.